# Can I share a wifi connection (not 3G) from my phone?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, android, mobile-phone

I have a Samsung S3 and a Windows laptop. For some reason or the other laptops don't detect our school's wifi but mobiles do.

- I want to know if it is possible for me to share the wifi from my  phone with my laptop.
- Anyone who knows why the notebooks don't detect the wifi can tell me.
- And if there is a way I can make my laptop detect the wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured out that I can tether through USB only to share the WiFi with my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Wifi tethering in android is 3G to WiFi, not WiFi to WiFi. Practically, same network interface card cannot be used to connect two different networks (your school wifi and the wifi hotspot) simultaneously.

Your particular case is strange, but did you make sure your laptop supports 802.11 n? It may be possible that the wifi network of your school is 802.11n only and your laptop supports only 802.11a/b/g. Samsung S3 however does support 802.11n. This is however just a speculation.

For more reliable solution you should contact the network administrator at your school.

Comment: The radio signal is 802.11a